# Load .eps images to canvas with kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

Does anyone know if you can load eps images to a canvas with kineticjs? I want to set an image as a background with zooming ability, but non-vector images do not work well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**No--you can't load .eps files.**

I just retried and confirmed that loading .eps fails.

It's not really a KineticJs limitation. It's a limitation of the html img tag/Image() object which don't know how to decode and display .eps files.

FWIW, you could try converting your .eps to .svg if you have a significant investment in EPS files.  Both img and Image() know how to display .svg.